# How to do version control for a SVN repository subfolder?

Tags: svn, repository

Some time ago I worked with SVN while not being involved on its configuration (which was done by one of my bosses). At that time, each new project (doesn't matter how small) had his own, new and unique repository in SVN. So if I was just creating a new project, the first commit would be number 1, and some changes plus new commit would create number 2, etc.. while all work was done based on the entire project repository.

Now I'm working in another place where were are trying to organize our repositories a bit (and now I'm in command of the SVN configuration). My idea would be to create a single repository for each project, while this time each project will have more than just programming code - e.g., each will have at least 4 folders: documentation, hardware, software, physical; and each of last 3 folders will be divided in documentation and source.

Doing this way, how would the commit count system works? Suppose one would just develop the software part; so he would create a copy of my_project/software/src at his computer and start developing his code. After that, he desires to do a commit: in doing that, would the entire repository go to commit nº 2 or only the used folder would go to the next number while the main repository continues in version nº 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Subversion, revision numbers refer to the entire repository, rather than individual files or folders.